# Is it possible to allow zip files to be uploaded in Wordpress?

Tags: uploads

Is it possible to allow zip files to be uploaded in Wordpress?

I have the following code but it doesn't work.

```
function custom_upload_mimes($existing_mimes = array()) {

// Add *.EPS files to Media upload
    $existing_mimes['eps'] = 'application/postscript';
// Add *.AI files to Media upload
    $existing_mimes['ai'] = 'application/postscript';
// Add *.AI files to Media upload
    $existing_mimes['3ds'] = 'application/postscript';
// Add *.dwg files to Media upload
    $existing_mimes['dwg'] = 'application/acad';
// Add *.dwg files to Media upload
    $existing_mimes['dwg'] = 'application/x-acad';
// Add *.dwg files to Media upload
    $existing_mimes['dwg'] = 'application/autocad_dwg';
// Add *.dwg files to Media upload
    $existing_mimes['dwg'] = 'application/dwg';
// Add *.dwg files to Media upload
    $existing_mimes['dwg'] = 'application/x-dwg';
// Add *.dwg files to Media upload
    $existing_mimes['dwg'] = 'application/x-autocad';
// Add *.dwg files to Media upload
    $existing_mimes['dwg'] = 'drawing/dwg';
//add .zip
    $existing_mimes['zip'] = 'application/zip';

    return $existing_mimes;
}

add_filter('upload_mimes', 'custom_upload_mimes');
```

Comment: Please explain "it doesn't seem to work".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a action that works on my site:

```
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'custom_upload_mimes');
function custom_upload_mimes ( $existing_mimes=array() ) {
    // add your extension to the mimes array as below
    $existing_mimes['zip'] = 'application/zip';
    $existing_mimes['gz'] = 'application/x-gzip';
    return $existing_mimes;
}
```

Comment: Not working for me at wp5

Answer (score 10):

If you are using WP MultiSite you can configure the behavior the following way (tested in WP 3.8.1):

- Go to the network settings in your browser: `http://example.com/wp-admin/network/settings.php`
- Scroll down to the bottom of the settings page and you will find a list of allowed file types, add `zip` to it.

Comment: weird when adding zip file, button upload doesn't respond any more.

Comment: Drag and drop works though

Answer (score 2):

In 5.0.3 (probably already earlier): For multisite (at least), you can edit the allowed extensions and add zip in the network settings. No need to edit files anymore.

My Sites > Network Admin > Settings > Upload file types